# How do I get LaraDock to use yum instead of apt-get?

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

I am trying to setup a container using laradock with the following command:

`docker-compose up -d nginx mysql`

The problem is I am getting the following error:

```
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
ERROR: Service 'workspace' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -yqq     && apt-get -yqq install nasm' returned a non-zero code: 100`
```

Is there a way to get it to use yum instead of apt-get?

(I'm a server noob, thought docker would be easy and it seems that it is. Just can't figure out why it's trying to use apt-get instead of yum. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read about the problems with different package system: [Getting apt-get on an alpine container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389749/getting-apt-get-on-an-alpine-container?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Most official docker images are available with different version of Linux (alpine, debian, cent). I would rather create a own Dockerfile and change "FROM x:y" than use different package systems.

But, read the linked comment.