# Create pre baked docker images with specific browser(latest chrome) and OS (alpine)

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, alpine-linux

I wanted to create image that includes latest alpine OS, latest chrome browser and a gitlab repo.
When I tried to build image using docker build, I am getting this following error.

### ERROR [ 3/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     software-properties-common    unzip     curl     x  2.8s

> [ 3/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     software-properties-common    unzip     curl     xvfb:
> #6 2.340 /bin/sh: apt-get: not found

---

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y     software-properties-common    unzip     curl     xvfb]: exit code: 127

Comment: You are using a base image which is not bundeled with apt. Either switch your base image or use the apk system. You might want to look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389749/getting-apt-get-on-an-alpine-container

Comment: You need to install package using apk not apt