# how to use apt/sudo in alpine-based docker image

Tags: dockerfile, alpine-linux, apt

I am currently writing a docker file that has to be based on alpine (the top line is `FROM alpine:latest`. I wish to use tools such as `sudo` and `curl` (by running a shell script from the dockerfile) which are normally avaialble on linux/mac, and to do this I have tried running `RUN apt update && apt-get install sudo -y` - however these don't seem to be available with alpine. Would anyone know how to get `apt` after basing off alpine, or another method of obtaining basic tools like sudo and curl? I've tried using apk (e.g. `RUN apk add apt-get`) but I always get an error like `apt-get (no such package):`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> another method of obtaining basic tools like sudo and curl?

I believe alpine uses `apk` instead of `apt`

Try something like this to install basic tools like `curl` and `sudo`

```
RUN apk add curl sudo
```

Comment: this seems to work for sudo and curl, but I also have apt commands like apt-get in the shell script that I want to run, and ```RUN apk add apt-get``` results in ```apt-get (no such package):```, even after running ```RUN apk update``` - would you know how to address this?

Comment: @SaboBoz you can't. `apt` is the package manager of Debian and Debian-based distributions ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software))). Alpine uses `apk` as its package manager, not `apt`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400219/2123530